# SharePoint list webpart connections option not visible

Tags: sharepoint, connection, web-parts, webpart-connection

I want to connect two list webparts. The problem is that when I go to "Edit Web Part -> Connections" this option "Connections" doesn't apperar.

Searching on google found this: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/connect-data-in-web-parts-HA010024105.aspx. There is a paragraph that says: "The Web Part menu may not be enabled or visible on your Web Part Page for several reasons, including that the Web Part or the zone does not support connections, you are using a browser that is not compatible with Windows SharePoint Services, or **connections are disabled on your site**"

I think connections are disable on my site. Where can I enable connections on a SharePoint site?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6):

Ha ha.  In Internet Explorer 11, you have to view Sharepoint sites in "Compatibility Mode"!  Imagine that!  Without Compatibility Mode, IE won't display the connection menus - but Firefox and Chrome will!  Apparently, [this is even a problem with Sharepoint 2013](http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/233685.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

I saw this problem even when Connections were enabled.

The workaround was to choose Edit Web Part and Click "Apply". This magically made the connection menu appear. However when the page is reloaded, the workaround needs to be applied again.

Comment: Worked for me after much playing around. This includes using IE11 on Win2008R2 server, in compatibility mode.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure if I remember correctly, but I had the same issue last week.

First you need access to the central administration at the sharepoint host.

In there, you have to click on "Application Managment" -> "Manage Web Applications"
Then select your web app and click on Web Part Security in the ribbon. If i remember right you should find an option there to allow connections between webparts.

Comment: This option is on by default. wiki page might be the issue

Answer (score 1):

Here in my experience I found that on wiki page web part connection is not possible, if you want to connect two web parts or two list, go and add your lists, or webpart onto webpart page, and on edit page connect them, ok.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issue with placing filter web parts on a wiki page. The filter web part is not visible and it's impossible to select the webpart menu when in page edit mode.

I encountered it a few times. Like user2780851 states. Enable the publishing features, add a new (publishing) page (so in the 'pages' library not in the 'sitepages' library). When you add the filter webparts on this publishing page all the menu options (and the connection option) will be available.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get things to redisplay without using compatibility mode.  In IE 11, what I had to do was hit F12 to pull up the developer menu, and then under the emulation tab, I switched my user agent to Internet Explorer 10, and then it started working correctly.  My problem that lead me to this thread was that my web part menu wasn't displaying at all.  This is a serious Microsoft fail.  Probably why they are planning to abandon IE altogether.  Good riddance, says I.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that this issue has caused a lot of confusion, and led people to *incorrectly* think that connections between web parts isn't available on wiki pages.

The Connections option will appear as long as you are in the edit mode of any web part on the page - it doesn't have to be a web part which will be involved in the connection.

Answer (score 0):

First you need access to the central administration at the sharepoint host.

In there, you have to click on "Application Managment" -> "Manage Web Applications" Then select your web app and click on Web Part Security in the ribbon. If i remember right you should find an option there to allow connections between webparts.

this is answer right i did it and it works